# submit should not redirect to another page in HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a HTML form which reads some data and saves in the text file with help of PHP. The form's HTML code looks like below.

**What is happening now:** 
1. once i click on `submit` button it redirects to the 'myprocessing.php'
2. successfully saving in `data.txt`

**The help i required on** 
1. when i click on `submit` it shouldn't redirect me to the php page, it should stay on the HTML form page 
2. it should show the php file's output on the same HTML page 
In simple words, I want to stay on the HTML page itself. Since I'm pretty new to HTML and PHP, struggling much to do these. Thanks in advance :-)

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
     <form action="myprocessing.php" method="POST">
     <input name="field1" type="text" />
     <input name="field2" type="text" />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
     </form>
<a href='data.txt'>Show data</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my data prcoessing PHP file.

```
<?php
echo "starting...";
if(isset($_POST['myTextBox']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
    $data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . "\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('data.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
if($ret === false) {
    die('There was an error writing this file');
}
else {
    echo "$ret bytes written to file";
}
echo "Ended...";
}
else {
die('no post data to process');
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to use AJAX if you don't want to change page.

Comment: Thanks, any examples pls.

Comment: www.google.com/?q=AJAX+PHP+Form

Comment: here you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php/14217926#14217926

Comment: If you don't want to use ajax, replace the html page with a PHP page, direct the form to the same page and detect postbacks with PHP

Comment: so now your question is like jquery ajax form ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write php code in same html file and use **`isset()`** function to check for `$_POST` data

Try this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2']))
{
echo "starting...";
if(isset($_POST['myTextBox']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
    $data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . "\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('data.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
if($ret === false) {
    die('There was an error writing this file');
}
else {
    echo "$ret bytes written to file";
}
echo "Ended...";
}
else {
die('no post data to process');
}
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
     <form action="current_page.php" method="POST">
     <input name="field1" type="text" />
     <input name="field2" type="text" />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
     </form>
<a href='data.txt'>Show data</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this is correct, AJAX is always nice to save some time and resources

Comment: Thanks mate, this works well as a PHP page. I guess i have to switch the page from HTML to PHP. Let me also try the ajax code too.

Answer (score 3):

Try below. Call `refresh_div()` on button click :-

```
<div class="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function refresh_div() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:'YOUR PHP page url',
            type:'POST',
            success:function(results) {
                jQuery(".result").html(results);
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: lol quite same code also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php/14217926#14217926

Comment: Yes.. But I think he doesnot want to go with AJAX :P

Comment: Literally no way to avoid using JavaScript and "AJAX" if you want to avoid the page navigation.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
     <form action="" method="POST" name="testForm" id="testForm">
         <input name="field1" type="text" />
         <input name="field2" type="text" />
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
     </form>
<a href='data.txt'>Show data</a>
<div class="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

add the name and id for form tag. if you keep action as blank, it will submit your form to current page itself.
You need a ajax call to perform as per your requirement.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( "#testForm" ).on( "submit", function( event )
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:'myprocessing.php',
            type:'POST',
            data: $("#testForm").serialize()
            success:function(results) {
                jQuery(".result").html(results);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

</script>
```

Dont forget to put a return false at the end. If we dont put return false, it will submit your form after the ajax call.